# How to access an element based on the element appears before it in python list

Tags: python, list, indexing

In python list, I would like to access elements based on an element that appears before them. So for example, in a given list such as:

```
x = [1,2,25,1,67,8,9,1,99]
```

I would like to filter out `2,67,99` since they all have `1` preceding them. I was thinking about using index but index only returns the first element.

Comment: `enumerate` might come in handy...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use `indexing` and `for` loop.

```
my_list = [1,2,25,1,67,8,9,1,99]
for i in range(len(my_list)): # len() returns length of an array
    if my_list[i] == 1: # here you check if 'i' element of my_list is equal to 1
        try:
            print(my_list[i+1]) # here you are printing 'i+1' element of my_list
        except IndexError:
            pass
```

result of this code is:

```
2
67
99
```

Comment: What if the last element of the list is `1`?

Comment: sweet wasnt thinking about that

Comment: @werkritter right, but i don't think he needs `try...except` statements. He's starting with python.

Comment: lol i have some experience with python and i just wasnt thinking straight

Comment: Upvote for showing EAFP. But @Laszlowaty even if the OP was a newbie you would want to add exceptions as it is better to learn good methods at first than to repent later. All the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) along with list slicing as

```
>>> x = [1,2,25,1,67,8,9,1,99]
>>> for i,j in zip(x[:-1],x[1:]):
...     if i==1:
...        print j
... 
2
67
99
```

This can be written in a single list comprehension as

```
[j for i,j in zip(x[:-1],x[1:]) if i==1]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use list comprehension and enumerate(), like this:

```
>>> [y for i, y in enumerate(x[1:]) if x[i] == 1]
[2, 67, 99]
```